# $text command not supported azure-cosmos-mongodb error, which version is supported?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

How to query for partial text search on all/any fields in a document using azure cosmos API mongodb 3.5.9?In documentation, I found that $text is the one which is used for this case but that does not support my application. Can we use $regex or $match? If yes, How?

Here is what I tried:

Error:{
"ok": 0,
"code": 115,
"codeName": "CommandNotSupported"
}
Query:

```
db.db(config.mongodb.dbname).collection(collectionname).find({$text: { $search: "\"test\"" }} ).sort({createdDate: -1}).limit(limit).skip(skip).toArray((err, res) => {console.log(res)});
```

Which version supports $text?  or any other command which performs same as $text?

Any suggestions appreciated...

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

$text is not supported. You can use regex like this, find({x:{$regex: /^abc$/})

Comment: by 'x' you mean field name? How to search on all the fields because the search term may be in any field as it is a global search in table.

Comment: If what you're looking is search you'd have to use Azure Search. Can learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb?toc=/azure/cosmos-db/toc.json&bc=/azure/cosmos-db/breadcrumb/toc.json).